# Scala: How can I get an escaped representation of a string?

Tags: string, scala, escaping

Basically, what I'd like to do is have:

```
 // in foo.scala
 val string = "this is a string\nover two lines"
 println(string)
 println(foo(string))
```

Do this:

```
% scala foo.scala
this is a string
over two lines
"this is a string\nover two lines"
```

Basically looking for an analog of ruby's `String#inspect` or haskell's `show :: String -> String`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This question is a bit old but I stumbled over it while searching for a solution myself and was dissatisfied with the other answers because they either are not safe (replacing stuff yourself) or require an external library.

I found a way to get the escaped representation of a string with the scala standard library (>2.10.0) which is safe. It uses a little trick:

Through runtime reflection you can can easily obtain a representation of a literal string expression. The tree of such an expression is returned as (almost) scala code when calling it's `toString` method. This especially means that the literal is represented the way it would be in code, i.e. escaped and double quoted.

```
def escape(raw: String): String = {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
  Literal(Constant(raw)).toString
}
```

The `escape` function therefore results in the desired code-representation of the provided raw string (including the surrounding double quotes):

```
scala> "\bHallo" + '\n' + "\tWelt"
res1: String =
?Hallo
        Welt

scala> escape("\bHallo" + '\n' + "\tWelt")
res2: String = "\bHallo\n\tWelt"
```

This solution is admittedly abusing the reflection api but IMHO still safer and more maintainable than the other proposed solutions.

Comment: Do you know how to unescape use with reflection?

Comment: @Renkai you don't need reflection for this. You can use StringContext: `StringContext.treatEscapes(res2)`. Leaves the double quotes though

Comment: `StringContext.treatEscapes` does the opposite: it converts "\\t" to "\t".

Comment: @Renkai To unescape and remove the double-quotes: `StringContext.treatEscapes(escapedString).drop(1).dropRight(1)`

Answer (score 26):

I'm pretty sure this isn't available in the standard libraries for either Scala or Java, but it is in [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html):

```
scala> import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava

scala> escapeJava("this is a string\nover two lines")
res1: java.lang.String = this is a string\nover two lines
```

You could easily add the quotation marks to the escaped string if you wanted, of course.

Answer (score 12):

The scala.reflect solution actually works fine. When you do not want to pull in that whole library, this is what it seems to do under the hood (Scala 2.11):

```
def quote (s: String): String = "\"" + escape(s) + "\""
def escape(s: String): String = s.flatMap(escapedChar)

def escapedChar(ch: Char): String = ch match {
  case '\b' => "\\b"
  case '\t' => "\\t"
  case '\n' => "\\n"
  case '\f' => "\\f"
  case '\r' => "\\r"
  case '"'  => "\\\""
  case '\'' => "\\\'"
  case '\\' => "\\\\"
  case _    => if (ch.isControl) "\\0" + Integer.toOctalString(ch.toInt) 
               else              String.valueOf(ch)
}

val string = "\"this\" is a string\nover two lines"
println(quote(string)) // ok
```

Answer (score 2):

If I compile these:

```
object s1 {
val s1 = "this is a string\nover two lines"
}

object s2 {
val s2 = """this is a string
over two lines"""
}
```

I don't find a difference in the String, so I guess: There is no possibility, to find out, whether there was was a "\n" in the source.

But maybe I got you wrong, and you would like to get the same result for both?

```
 "\"" + s.replaceAll ("\\n", "\\\\n").replaceAll ("\\t", "\\\\t") + "\""
```

The second possibility is:

```
val mask = Array.fill (3)('"').mkString 
mask + s + mask

res5: java.lang.String = 
"""a
b"""
```

Test:

```
scala> val s = "a\n\tb"
s: java.lang.String = 
a
    b

scala>     "\"" + s.replaceAll ("\\n", "\\\\n").replaceAll ("\\t", "\\\\t") + "\""
res7: java.lang.String = "a\n\tb"

scala> mask + s + mask
res8: java.lang.String = 
"""a
    b"""
```

Comment: (U) I'm looking for a function that escapes a string, where escaping a string involves transforming all the "\n" to "\\n", "\t" to "\\t", etc, and possibly enclosing the result in double quotes (depending on the language).

Comment: On compilation, at least the \n is transformed into a 0A (if you happen to look through a hexeditor). I bet, you will see an equivalent for \t - the same as if you had used a tab with the Tab-Key. Okay - you need a `"` before and behind the String; I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: `mask` can be written as `"\""*3`

Answer (score 2):

You could build your own function pretty easily, if you don't want to use the apache library:

```
scala> var str = "this is a string\b with some \n escapes \t so we can \r \f \' \" see how they work \\";
str: java.lang.String = 
this is a string? with some 
escapes      so we can 
' " see how they work \

scala> print(str.replace("\\","\\\\").replace("\n","\\n").replace("\b","\\b").replace("\r","\\r").replace("\t","\\t").replace("\'","\\'").replace("\f","\\f").replace("\"","\\\""));
this is a string\b with some \n escapes \t so we can \r \f \' \" see how they work \\
```

Comment: Thanks--forgot about those, those are trickier to just "replace" back, also. I'll see if I can figure it out later.

Comment: my point being is that there's a LOT of edge cases with this, and I'd rather use a well-tested library than roll my own.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a cleaner way to implement this in Scala 3, but this is what I've come up with following @martin-ring approach:

```
import scala.quoted.*

inline def escape(inline raw: String): String = ${escapeImpl('{raw})}

def escapeImpl(raw: Expr[String])(using Quotes): Expr[String] =
  import quotes.reflect.*
  Literal(StringConstant(raw.show)).asExprOf[String]
```