# Scala. Split line regex returns unexpected empty String

Tags: regex, scala

Please see the example below. I create a multiline String and then try to split it. It works fine except the first line. By default split method doesn't return delimiters. So, I wonder what is so special about the beginning of the line that it returns `""`. And how to update the regex to avoid it.

```
scala> val Shakespear =
     |     """
     |       |To be,
     |       | or not
     |       |to be:
     |     """.stripMargin
Shakespear: String =
"
To be,
 or not
to be:
    "

scala> Shakespear.split("""[\s]+""")
res3: Array[String] = Array("", To, be,, or, not, to, be:)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of updating *regex*, how about [trim](http://otfried.org/scala/string.html) the white spaces at both ends, and then split:

```
Shakespear.trim.split("\\s+")
// res22: Array[String] = Array(To, be,, or, not, to, be:)
```

As for why you have an empty string, you have a new line character at the beginning of the string which is also captured by `\\s`, and splitting on it gives you an empty string since there is nothing in front of the delimiter.

Here is the raw representation of your string (escape borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913971/scala-how-can-i-get-an-escaped-representation-of-a-string)):

```
def escape(raw: String): String = {
    import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
    Literal(Constant(raw)).toString
}

escape(Shakespear)
// res24: String = "\nTo be,\n or not\nto be:\n          "
```

If you don't want to split on new line character, use " " instead:

```
Shakespear.split(" ")

//res26: Array[String] =
//Array("
//To", "be,
//", or, not
//to, "be:
//")
```